# CarrierWave remote upload from model not controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, instagram, railscasts

I'm working on a Rails app which consumes the Instagram API to get a set of pictures. I want to store those pictures locally using CarrierWave to remote upload them. I know if you're using a controller, you can supply a url as the `remote_image_url` variable and CarrierWave natively knows what to do.

My question is: how can I get CarrierWave to do this from the Model? As I don't have a controller since I'm getting everything from the API.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `remote_image_url` anywhere, not just in a controller.

Comment: Seems to work but calling object.image.url(:thumb) now returns a url which doesn't match the folder names